# Query ETC1 compression support without OpenGL context in Android?

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm compressing some textures using ETC1 when my application starts. I also have a fallback method if ETC1 is not supported.

The problem:

```
ETC1Util.isETC1Supported(); // Returns false with no available gl context even if the device supports it.
```

So my question: Is there a way to query this without a current gl context or I will have to make my splash screen render using a GLSurfaceView in order to get that flag ?

I've read that i can filter devices with no such support in AndroidMarket but that is not an option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to query OpenGL extension without OpenGL context.

But if you use OpenGL ES 2.0, then ETC will always be available there: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-gl-texture-element.html

> GL_OES_compressed_ETC1_RGB8_texture
>
> Ericsson texture compression. Specified in OpenGL ES 2.0 and available in all Android-powered devices that support OpenGL ES 2.0.